# how do I get the drop down to close after selection has been made?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

originally I wanted to just filter based on the selected type. I then decided I wanted to mock a dropdown using the `<li>` instead of the `<select>` because I had just figured out the filter and thought it would be faster. I was wrong. I'm sure it a simple fix to do with the "click"

I tried dissecting the code snippets to their simplest parts and was able to get each of the features working separately, but have been unsuccessful getting them to work together.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="init">[SELECT]</li>
    <li data-value="value 1">Option 1</li>
    <li data-value="value 2">Option 2</li>
    <li data-value="value 3">Option 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="init">[SELECT]</li>
    <li id="opt1" data-value="value 1" class="filter">Option 1</li>
    <li id="opt2" data-value="value 2" class="filter">Option 2</li>
    <li id="reset"  data-value="value 3" class="filter">Option 3</li>
</ul>
```

when clicking on a selection, the expected behavior is that the selection box is populated by the selected type. Currently, the dropdown remains open and all selection types are visible

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't using a `select`? It has all that functionality built in

Comment: Where is the code that makes this act like a dropdown? Are you using a framework like Bootstrap?

Comment: If you're not wanting to use ``select`` for some reason, you're going to have to do this with javascript. (1) what's wrong with ``select``? (2) Have you attempted any javascript?

Comment: please add your css and any javascript you have tried